# Can't parse this int

Tags: c#, int

I got a simple question, I got error when I do:
I can't convert it to int...

```
string buy = "16.11";
int _buy = (int.Parse(buy) * 9);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Int stands for Integer. You can't parse delimited value to int. Change it to double or decimal. For example:

```
string buy = 16.11;
double _buy = double.Parse(buy) * 9;
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, `16.11` is a *float number*, so you have to parse into, say, `Double` and the *round up* to `int`:

```
string buy = "16.11";
int _buy = (int)(Double.Parse(buy) * 9 + 0.5); // 0.5 for rounding up
```

if `_buy` is actually a *float* or *decimal*, treat it as being *float* or *decimal*

```
 string buy = "16.11";
 // We usually use Decimal for money
 Decimal _buy = Decimal.Parse(buy) * 9;
```

Comment: you can do `int.Parse(double.Parse(buy))` instead of adding 0.5

Comment: @M.kazem Akhgary: `int.Parse()` wants `String`; yet another issue is values like `155.99999999` so `+ 0.5` is, INHO, *safier*

Answer (score 0):

A string variable cannot hold a decimal value, your string initialization is also wrong, you can do like the following, a string should be within double quotes, or else you should add `.ToString()`:

```
string buy = "16.11";
int _buy = (int)(Double.Parse(buy) * 9 + 0.5);
```